# Returning two values in Javascript - return [foo, bar] vs return foo + " " + bar

Tags: javascript, return

I'm just going through some hackerrank challenges and this cropped up in my function below.

The second method of **return foo + " " + bar** gave me an error, but the first method worked.  Why?  What are the differences between the two methods of returning here?

Edit:- Full source for the interests of a commenter...

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', inputStdin => {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', _ => {
    inputString = inputString.trim().split('\n').map(str => str.trim());

    main();
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}

/*
 * Complete the solve function below.
 */
function solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2) {
    /*
     * Write your code here.
     */
    let aScore = 0;
    let bScore = 0;

    function compare(valA, valB){
        if (valA < valB){
            bScore += 1;
        }
        else if (valA == valB){
        }
        else {
            aScore += 1;
        }
    }

    compare(a0, b0);
    compare(a1, b1);
    compare(a2, b2);
    return [aScore, bScore];

}

function main() {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

    const a0A1A2 = readLine().split(' ');

    const a0 = parseInt(a0A1A2[0], 10);

    const a1 = parseInt(a0A1A2[1], 10);

    const a2 = parseInt(a0A1A2[2], 10);

    const b0B1B2 = readLine().split(' ');

    const b0 = parseInt(b0B1B2[0], 10);

    const b1 = parseInt(b0B1B2[1], 10);

    const b2 = parseInt(b0B1B2[2], 10);

    let result = solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2);

    ws.write(result.join(" ") + "\n");

    ws.end();
}
```

Comment: `return foo + " " + bar gave me an error` - what error? how are you calling solve, and what are you doing with the result?

Comment: both `return` methods work - https://jsfiddle.net/emd5h094/

Comment: "no output from stdout" - but there's other hackerrank code in there.  my question is that both returns look the same if printed to console, but they must be different.  Either that or there are some unit tests on hackerrank behind the scenes.

Comment: `no output from stdout` - that doesn't sound like any javascript error I've ever seen ... what javascript environment is this? but of course the returned value is different ... one is an `array`, the other is a `string`

Comment: Yeah sorry it's probably just a custom error from their platform.  But it's in a Node environment.  I edited the full source into my post for you to see.  The error comes from line -     ws.write(result.join(" ") + "\n"); - towards the bottom, when I try the alternative return method.

Does it have something to do with 'use strict'; ?

Comment: a string has no `join` method - simple - this is why I asked what you are doing with the result of calling `solve` - because that was always going to be where the error occured

Comment: Ah.  So when I return the values like val1 + " " + val2, the whole line is then treated as a string.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `return [aScore, bScore]` you are returning an array with two elements while `return aScore + " " + bScore` returns a single string

Comment: Thanks Pramesh - I suspected that was the case.